# How to indent Org Babel list output with multiline text correctly?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, indentation

I'm using Babel to generate some text in an Org file. I'm using `:results value list` header switch [described here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) to format the output in Org's list structure. It doesn't quite format multiline text the way it is formatted in my regular list structures.

This is src block:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value list
'("Foo1\nBar1" "Foo2\n\nBar2")
#+end_src
```

This is what I get:

```
#+RESULTS:
- Foo1
Bar1
- Foo2

Bar2
```

This is what I expect (This is what I get if I just type in the text in a regular org file):

```
#+RESULTS:
- Foo1
  Bar1
- Foo2

  Bar2
```

Comment: I don't know how to align and it sounds like a (minor) bug to me, but other than the ugliness, does it cause any problems? You might want to report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: It is probably a bug. The problem is actually not ugliness. Problem is that by definition an Org list ends when there is an out-indented line. In my example this makes the list end after the first `Foo1`. So if I want to clear the result using `C-c C-v k` or if I run the block again only the first line gets removed.

Comment: You are right: it's more serious than I thought. Please report it.